# Hibernate second level cache cleared

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ehcache, hibernate-search

We are use using Hibernate Search 3.4.2 Final and EHCACHE 2.3.1 in one of our applications. The data indexed by Hibernate Search is read-only. For performance reasons, we are loading the complete data into the second-level cache.

For some time something happens accidentally that clears the complete second-level cache. That must be something that is not explicitly triggered by our Code.

Is there anyone who has a presumption? Is there a chance that the usage of Hibernate Search inside a rollbacked transaction can lead to this behaviour?

Edit1:

This is our EHCACHE configuration:

```
<ehcache updateCheck="false">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ds42" />

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="200000" eternal="true"
              statistics="true" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="false"
              diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="3600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
</ehcache>
```

Comment: Could it just be the size of the cache, i.e. the data gets too big (maybe some other data in the same cache) which causes the cache to drop something?

Comment: I'm no Hibernate Search expert but we're using it as well and AFAIK it only reads entities so it shouldn't affect the 2nd level cache.

Comment: sounds like log forensic job

Comment: Do you execute any DML native queries? If so, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34418400/4754790) could be useful.

Comment: May be it exceeds "tiimetoliveSeconds" it is an entry after which the cache gets cleared and it goes back to db to get the latest data Eg    <cache name="XXX"
           maxElementsInMemory="300"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="12000"
           timeToLiveSeconds="12000"
           diskPersistent="false"
           diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"  />

Comment: I've added our EHCACHE configuration.

Comment: Hibernate Search would never invalidate the 2nd level cache, so I would suggest exploring the updates caused by actually not-rolled-back transactions of Hibernate ORM. Try to get a stacktrace from an invalidation?

Comment: Thanks for all your tips. With the tip from @Sanne I've found this [link](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2011/10/08/impact-of-native-sql-queries-on-hibernates-second-level-cache/) .This looked like a perfect mach for me, because we use native queries in some cases. So I added this: `query.unwrap(org.hibernate.SQLQuery.class).addSynchronizedQuerySpace("");` to all native queries. The problem exists anyway.

Comment: Ok the problem is solved. There were still some native queries without this addition. I've added `query.unwrap(org.hibernate.SQLQuery.class).addSynchronizedQuerySpace("");` and now the cache remains filled. Thanks for all your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this "surprising" behaviour can be found inside [this article](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2011/10/08/impact-of-native-sql-queries-on-hibernates-second-level-cache/).

Add

```
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.SQLQuery.class).addSynchronizedQuerySpace("");
```

to prevent Hibernate from clearing the second-level cache.