# How to invalidate cache l1?

Tags: java, hibernate

How to invalidate cache l1 in hibernate? How does it looks in practice? I was reading about invalidate cache l2 [Native query and caching mechanism of Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973872/native-query-and-caching-mechanism-of-hibernate/23974103#23974103)

but how does it looks for cache level 1?

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/understanding-hibernate-first-level-cache-with-example/

Comment: `entityManager.clear()`