# HazelcastCacheRegionFactory entities removed from map after 30 seconds

Tags: hibernate, caching, hazelcast

Using Hibernate 5.4.2 and hazelcast-all 4.1 with HazelcastCacheRegionFactory.

Marked as cachable entities are added to cache map successfully but deleted after ~30 sec, even though not removed or updated in DB.

What could be the root cause and/or some default 30 sec. eviction configuration ?

Followed that [wiki](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate).

Thanks,
Pavel

Comment: Do you add any map config to Hazelcast config which can affect the cache regions - i.e. changing the default config or using map names with wildcards? Otherwise the default map config will end up with non-expiring entries until the max size is hit.

Comment: No configuration, running with default Hazelcast configurations, first trying to understand the early eviction issue.

Comment: Caused by native update query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973872/native-query-and-caching-mechanism-of-hibernate/23974103#23974103